# JavaFX Popup not shown if owner window is not visible

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, popup, javafx-8

Trying to set a Stage as owner of a Popup, but the Popup does not appear if the owner is not the main Stage of the application.

```
public void popup(Window owner, String mensagem) {
    Popup popup = new Popup();
    popup.setAutoHide(true);
    popup.setHideOnEscape(true);

    Label label = new Label(mensagem);
    label.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.CORNSILK, null, null)));

    popup.getContent().add(label);
    popup.setOnShown((event) -> {
        FadeTransition fade = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(5), label);
        fade.setOnFinished((e) -> {
            popup.hide();
        });
        fade.play();
    });

    popup.show(owner);
}
```

The child Stage:

```
public class JanelaModal extends Stage {

    public JanelaModal(String title) {
        super(StageStyle.DECORATED);
        setTitle(title);
        initOwner(Main.getInstance().getStage());
        initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        setResizable(false);
    }

    public void setGui(Parent gui) {
        if (getScene() != null) {
            getScene().setRoot(gui);
        } else {
            setScene(new Scene(gui));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call `show(...)` on your child stage before showing the popup.

Using your class `JanelaModal` I wrote a simple test Java FX application. This is the Main class

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private static Main instance;
    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        instance = this;
        this.stage = stage;
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        //primaryStage.show(); //Don't show main stage

        JanelaModal modal = new JanelaModal("TEST");
        modal.setWidth(300);
        modal.setHeight(300);
        modal.show();
        popup(modal, "Test message");
    }

    //Copied and pasted from the question post
    public void popup(Window owner, String mensagem) {
        Popup popup = new Popup();
        popup.setAutoHide(true);
        popup.setHideOnEscape(true);

        Label label = new Label(mensagem);
        label.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.CORNSILK, null, null)));

        popup.getContent().add(label);
        popup.setOnShown((event) -> {
            FadeTransition fade = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(5), label);
            fade.setOnFinished((e) -> {
                popup.hide();
            });
            fade.play();
        });

        popup.show(owner);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static Main getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public Stage getStage() {
        return stage;
    }
}
```

And this is the result

[image: The test application]

The popup is shown in the "child" Stage. If you call

```
popup(modal, "Test message");
```

But you don't call

```
modal.show();
```

The popup (and the stage) will not show.

Hope I helped, somehow :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems the owner window must be visible when the popup is shown. In my case the child window is being closed, so the main window must be the owner of the popup. I wonder why the documentation does not mention that, it is not so obvious.